# Как объяснить использование сослагательного наклонения?

Tags: наклонение

Пример:

Если бы ты не привёз мне паспорт в аэропорт, я бы не улетел на конференцию.

Как я понимаю, это констатация: кто-то привёз паспорт и персонаж смог благодаря этому попать на конференцию. Так?

У Шведовой читаю, что ***если бы не*** оформляет утверждение. 
Так почему же используется сослагательное наклонение в этом условном предложении, если действие было реальным?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смысл, который вы правильно вывели (оба действия реально имели место), в этом предложении выражен обратным способом, через гипотетическую ситуацию, при которой обоих связанных действий не было. Здесь подчёркивается важность в прошлом одного действия  (доставку паспорта) для осуществления другого реально произошедшего действия (улететь). Этим способом можно (как в этом примере) либо подчеркнуть неприятность ситуации в прошлом, либо косвенно выразить признательность тому, кто тогда выручил. Что касается выражения "*оформляет утверждение*", вероятно, автор имел в виду, что **утверждение** реальности упомянутых действий выражено **в форме** сослагательного наклонения, причём **"если бы не"** - признак реальности действия.

Answer (score 1):

Придаточные условия имеют частные подтипы:

**1) ирреально (нереальное) условие**, которое не осуществилось: Если бы не было дождя, мы пошли бы гулять.

Эти предложения называют контрфактическими, так как в реальности они не осуществились: Если бы ты не привёз мне паспорт в аэропорт, я бы не улетел на конференцию.

**2) потенциальное условие**, которое может осуществиться: Если не будет дождя, мы пойдем гулять.

Comment: В этом то и дело, Вера: действия БЫЛИ СОВЕРШЕНЫ: паспорт БЫЛ ПРИВЕЗЕН и человек БЫЛ на конференции. 
мне только непонятно, почему для выражения реально произойдённых действий используется сослагательное наклонение...

Comment: Сослагательное наклонение указывает на ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНОСТЬ СИТУАЦИИ.  Мы знаем, что действие состоялось, но  РАССМАТРИВАЕМ гипотетическую  ситуацию, когда оно будто бы не состоялось, и определяем возможные последствия этого.